# DQL - Selecting multiple fields, but fetching only one - hiding fields from resultset

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

Given following DQL query:

```
SELECT
    p,
    (p.views * 0.1) + (p.likes * 0.9) as ratingPhoto
FROM
    AppBundle:Photo p
ORDER BY
    ratingPhoto DESC
```

My resultset will look like following:

```
array (size=14)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => object(Photo)
      'ratingPhoto' => string '1.42' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => object(Photo)
      'ratingPhoto' => string '1.31' (length=4)
...
```

Is there any DQL functionality so that I will only retrieve the `Photo` objects and exclude the other selected fields from the resultset? Here is what I'd expect as a result:

```
array (size=14)
  0 => object(Photo)
  1 => object(Photo)
...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is computed values in the `ORDER` clause and the [`HIDDEN`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#select-expressions) keyword.

In general, you have to do something like following:

```
SELECT
    a,
    b,
    (SOME_COMPUTATION()) AS computed
FROM
    ...
ORDER BY
    computed ASC
```

To "hide" the `computed` value from the resultset, since Doctrine ORM 2.3, you can use the `HIDDEN` clause:

```
SELECT
    a,
    b,
    (SOME_COMPUTATION()) AS HIDDEN computed
FROM
    ...
ORDER BY
    computed ASC
```

This is how your DQL would look like:

```
SELECT 
    p,
    (p.views * 0.1) + (p.likes * 0.9) AS HIDDEN ratingPhoto
FROM
    AppBundle:Photo p
ORDER BY
    ratingPhoto DESC
```

Comment: @httpete you should really consider upgrading. Doctrine 2.1 is not maintained anymore

Comment: I definitely will ! Thanks again, very clean answer

Answer (score -3):

You can rewrire your DQL as:

```
$dql = "SELECT p
FROM AppBundle:Photo p
ORDER BY ((p.views * 0.1) + (p.likes * 0.9)) DESC";
```

Comment: @DmitryKrasun please try your code before answering a question this way. This is not even supported in the EBNF as of http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#ebnf !